# Proximity search using eDismax

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, edismax, dismax

I have created a search engine using solr. I want to create a query such that if the user searches for the word "*college*", the score of the document which has the word "*famous*" in close proximity (within 2 words ie "*famous college*" or "*college is famous*") should be higher. If the word *famous* is not present in close proximity then it should calculate score based on the word "*college*" only.

What I want is something like this 
"famous college"~2^10 OR "college famous"~1^10 OR "college"

How to achieve this in eDismax?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a phrase search with a phrase slop of 2. For example setting defaults in `solrconfig.xml` might look something like:

```
  <requestHandler name="/phraseSearch" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="wt">xml</str>
        <str name="fl">Title</str>
        <str name="qf">Name^2 Description</str> <!-- The fields (and their weightings) to search in.-->
        <str name="rows">500</str>
        <str name="pf">Name^4 Description^2</str> <!-- Phrase field (and their weightings). Fields to search for closely located matches -->
        <str name="ps">2</str> <!-- Phrase slop. How many tokens apart must words be to be able to qualify as a phrase-->
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Controlling the phrase search in the query might look like:

```
http://mySolrHost:8983/solr/myEDismaxQuery?q=Title:famous+college&defType=edismax&pf=Title&ps=2
```

More information on phrase queries using eDismax can be found in the [Solr Reference page for eDismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser).

Comment: Can you please elaborate where to enter the word "famous" if I want to search whether famous lie in close proximity of my query "college". Also it should not consider famous in the query if its not there in close proximity

Comment: This will return result even if the document has only the word "famous"

Comment: You will need to change the 'Title' part of the search to whatever field you are using. You did not specific what was the name of the field you wished to search.

Comment: I understood that part. What I am saying is that the query that you have mentioned might also return the doc which has only the word famous and not temple. This is not what I want